# Summing up each row and column in Java

Tags: java, arrays, row, multiple-columns

```
/*
 * Programmer: Olawale Onafowokan
 * Date: February 6, 2014
 * Purpose: Prints the row and column averages
 */
class Lab4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] scores = {{ 20, 18, 23, 20, 16 },
            { 30, 20, 18, 21, 20 },
            { 16, 19, 16, 53, 24 },
            { 25, 24, 22, 24, 25 }};
        outputArray(scores);
    }

    public static void outputArray(int[][] array) {
        int sum= 0;
        int rowSize = array.length;
        int columnSize = array[0].length;
        System.out.println("rows=" + rowSize + "cols=" + columnSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
                sum += array[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println("Print the sum of rows = " + sum);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum = 0;
            sum = sum + array[i][j];
            // It is telling me the j can't be resolved
        }
    }
}
```

The program prints out:

```
rows=4cols=5
Print the sum of rows = 612
Print the sum of rows = 20358
Print the sum of rows = 652058
Print the sum of rows = 20866609
```

I don’t understand why it isn't adding up the numbers correctly. I am trying to add up each row and column. I am not even sure where these numbers are coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
sum += sum + array[i][j];
```

`sum += sum + array[i][j]` is the same as `sum = sum + sum + array[i][j]` (*you added sum twice*)

Should be:

`sum = sum + array[i][j];` **Or** `sum += array[i][j];`

If you want to print the sum of each **row only**, reset your `sum` to `0` for each iteration on outer `for-loop`

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    sum=0;
    ....
```

If you want to print the sum of each **column only**, you need to add this:

```
int[] colSum =new int[array[0].length];
```

Then inside `for-loop` , add

```
colSum[j]+=array[i][j];
```

So finally you will have this:

```
int[] colSum =new int[array[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){   
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){                
        sum += array[i][j];
        colSum[j] += array[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println("Print the sum of rows =" + sum);
}  
for(int k=0;k<colSum.length;k++){
    System.out.println("Print the sum of columns =" + colSum[k]);
}
```

Comment: I got it. But how would the formula change to do the columns ?

Comment: @user3286008 you want to print the sum of each `20,30,16,25`, `18,20,1924` and so on?

Comment: Yes for 20+30+16+20+25

Comment: Okay, I tried it  but for some reason it is telling the j can't be resolved    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    
    
    {   
      for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
      {                
        sum = sum + array[i][j]; 
         
      }
      
     System.out.println("Print the sum of rows =" + sum);
    }  
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     { sum= 0;
       sum = sum + array[i][j]; 
       
       
     }
    
    
  }
  
}

Comment: Oh, just one question how does for(int k=0;k<colSum.length;k++) work? did it just rename the  columns

Comment: you created new array here `int[] colSum =new int[array[0].length];` to store each sums of the columns. so you need loop to go through the array to print each of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrSort objArr = new ArrSort();
        int[][] arr = {
            {1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {1,2,3}
        };

        objArr.getColsSum(arr);

    }
}

class ArrSort {
    public void getColsSum(int[][] arg){
        int[] colsSum = new int[3];
        colsSum[0] = 0;
        colsSum[1] = 0;
        colsSum[2] = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<arg.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<arg[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arg[i][j] +" ");
                if(j==0) {
                    colsSum[j]+=arg[i][j];
                } else if(j==1) {
                    colsSum[j]+= arg[i][j];
                } else {
                    colsSum[j]+= arg[i][j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<colsSum.length; i++){
            System.out.print(colsSum[i] + " ");
        }
    } 
}
```

**DEMO**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {   
      sum=0;
      for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
      {                
        sum += array[i][j]; 

      }

     System.out.println("Print the sum of rows =" + sum);
    }
```

try intializing sum =0;

For Sum of Columns you could do this

```
class Sample{
    public static void main(String []args){
        int arr[][]={{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}};
        int sum=0;
        for(int col=0;col<arr[0].length;col++){
            for(int row=0;row<arr.length;row++){
                sum+=arr[row][col];
            }
            System.out.println("Sum is "+sum);
            sum=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop (controlled with i) executes once for each row.  If you want to sum all the numbers in one row, set `sum` to zero at the beginning of each loop.

If you have "sum = sum + x", that will add x to sum and store in sum.  If you write "sum += x", that will do the same thing.  But you have written "sum += sum + x", which adds in sum AND x to sum.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the operator "+=", simply use "=".

Answer (score 0):

this for loop of yours is out of scope btw.
check with the compiler:

output : when taking out sum = sum + array[i][j]

rows=4cols=5
Print the sum of rows = 97
Print the sum of rows = 206
Print the sum of rows = 334
Print the sum of rows = 454

after that it would work but it gives sum of all rows not breaking them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
        // It is telling me the j can't be resolved
    }
//j is out of scope there is no such thing as j in this loop
```

English: pseudo code

adding one set of row then stop.
r1
r2
r3
r4
or arrays if you want r[x]

each time cleaning the sum instead of adding them to each other.

so you need 4 sums of rows

and 5 sums of columns
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5

so you do a loop for horizontal summation 
and one vertical summation.

also don't put your name on top of the assignment. 


output after fix
rows=4cols=5
Print the sum of rows = 97
Print the sum of rows = 109
Print the sum of rows = 128
Print the sum of rows = 120
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

now you need to do this for columns 5 times

Answer (score 0):

"you don't have to use the operator "+=", simply use "="."

...
actually he needs the += but then he is using it wrong.

logically speaking his code is wrong.

it should be += then after each instance of the outer for loop he should be cutting it off
by resetting the sum of the value to 0 again to give out new values.